# How to use the path obtained from tkinter askdirectory in python as raw?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, path

I have a python `tkinter` code which will accept a file path using `askdirectory()`. The result is like this : `C:/Users/gfgf/gas`.
I need to pass it into `pandas read_excel`. But in pandas read_excel I give path as :`frame = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\gfgf\gas\doj.xlsx')`.

So how can I convert `C:/Users/gfgf/gas` into `C:\\Users\\gfgf\\gas\\doj.xlsx`

Comment: I think you are getting the directory name , look for another function to get the entire path with filenme, can you post your code

Comment: Forward slashes are acceptable to Windows, you don't need to convert the string.

Comment: are you getting any error, try my updated solution

Comment: Why do you think you need to convert the path? Did you try to use the path and get an error? If so, what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename 

root=tkinter.Tk()

def browse():
    file=askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files","*.xlsx")])
    print(file)


button1=tkinter.Button(root,text='Browse',command=browse)
button1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

`print(file)` will have the full path with filename

you can read it using `pd.read_excel(file) by making file as global`